# Getting ever while SQL script input as a string in the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

This is the code I used to run, but while running I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 34
> Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomers_Pager] --'RowNumber','asc',0,10,''
    (@sortColumn VARCHAR(50),
     @sortOrder VARCHAR(50),
     @OffsetValue INT,
     @PagingSize INT,
     @SearchText VARCHAR(50) )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
         'SELECT 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY document_id ASC) AS RowNumber,
               document_id AS ID,
               document_title AS Title,
               document_url AS Download,
               online_filing_link AS FileOnline,
               CASE 
                  WHEN LTRIM(document_fee) IS NULL THEN '' 
                  ELSE CASE 
                          WHEN LEN(document_fee) = 0 THEN ''
                          ELSE ''$'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, document_fee) 
                       END 
               END AS FilingFee ,
               CASE 
                  WHEN LTRIM(document_fee_enhanced) IS NULL THEN '' 
                  ELSE CASE 
                          WHEN LEN(document_fee_enhanced) = 0 THEN '' 
                          ELSE ''$'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, document_fee_enhanced)  
                       END 
               END AS EnhancedFee,
               COUNT(document_id) OVER() AS FilterTotalCount 
           FROM 
               documents';

    SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery +
                    ' WHERE ((''' + @SearchText + ''' <> '''' AND (document_title LIKE ''%' + @SearchText + '%'' OR FilingFee LIKE ''%' + @SearchText + '%'')) OR ('''+@SearchText+''' = ''''))';
    SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' ORDER BY ' + @sortColumn + ' ' + @sortOrder;
    SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ' OFFSET ' + CAST(@OffsetValue AS varchar(100)) + ' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + CAST(@PagingSize AS varchar(100)) + ' ROWS ONLY';
        
    EXEC (@sqlQuery); 
END
```

Comment: am using sqlserver 2017

Comment: when i try to add 2017 it is not able to add for me.

Comment: If you don't LOOK at the query your code generates, how do you expect to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

The error because the generated SQL statement syntax is invalid. The literals `THEN ''` should be `THEN ''''` so the resultant statement has matching quotes. I suggest you add a `PRINT` statement for the generated SQL during debugging like the below example.

More importantly, [use parameters](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/) for values that vary by execution instead of building the statement with literals for those values. Make sure the values for `@SortColumn` and `@sortOrder` are provided from a trusted source or validate the values against the catalog views in the proc code.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetCustomers_Pager
       @sortColumn VARCHAR(50)
     , @sortOrder VARCHAR(50)
     , @OffsetValue INT
     , @PagingSize INT
     , @SearchText VARCHAR(50)
AS

DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY document_id ASC) AS RowNumber,
            document_id AS ID,
            document_title AS Title,
            document_url AS Download,
            online_filing_link AS FileOnline,
            CASE 
                WHEN LTRIM(document_fee) IS NULL THEN '''' 
                ELSE CASE 
                        WHEN LEN(document_fee) = 0 THEN ''''
                        ELSE ''$'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, document_fee) 
                    END 
            END AS FilingFee ,
            CASE 
                WHEN LTRIM(document_fee_enhanced) IS NULL THEN '''' 
                ELSE CASE 
                        WHEN LEN(document_fee_enhanced) = 0 THEN '''' 
                        ELSE ''$'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, document_fee_enhanced)  
                    END 
            END AS EnhancedFee,
            COUNT(document_id) OVER() AS FilterTotalCount 
        FROM 
            documents';

SET @sqlQuery += N' WHERE ((@SearchText <> '''' AND (document_title LIKE ''%'' + @SearchText + ''%'' OR FilingFee LIKE ''%'' + @SearchText + ''%'')) OR (@SearchText = ''''))';
SET @sqlQuery += N' ORDER BY ' + @sortColumn + ' ' + @sortOrder;
SET @sqlQuery += N' OFFSET @OffsetValue ROWS FETCH NEXT @PagingSize ROWS ONLY;';

--use PRINT to debug SQL query text        
--PRINT @sqlQuery; 

EXEC sp_executesql 
      @sqlQuery
    , N'@OffsetValue INT, @PagingSize INT, @SearchText VARCHAR(50)'
    , @OffsetValue  = 0
    , @PagingSize = 10
    , @SearchText  = '';
GO

EXECUTE [dbo].[GetCustomers_Pager]
      @sortColumn ='RowNumber'
     ,@sortOrder  = 'asc'
     ,@OffsetValue  = 0
     ,@PagingSize = 10
     ,@SearchText  = '';
GO
```